# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: []

Tags: apex, class, error-messages

The code below is for an API that runs all day long. sometimes I get this error:UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW I made some research about this issue and I am using FOR UPDATE in the query but is still happening. Is there any way to manage this error and when it happens refresh the page immediately, for now it demands a human interaction to reload the page. Or somehow fix the query and get only available records. I will appreciate any help.

Class code:

```
public class InventoryAMZAPIController{


public InventoryAMZAPI2.CreateInboundShipmentPlanResult NewPlan{ get; set; }
public List<InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem> RemainingItems{ get; set; } 



public void CreatePlan(){

List<NRProducts__c> details = [SELECT NRName__c, Inventory_Update_Cycle__c, Active__c, isFBA__c   FROM NRProducts__c WHERE Inventory_Update_Cycle__c =true AND isFBA__c=true AND Active__c = true LIMIT 49 FOR UPDATE];
Map<String, InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem> itemsMap = new Map<String, InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem>();
if(!details.isEmpty()){
        RemainingItems = new List<InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem>();
        for(NRProducts__c rl : details){
            InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem item = new InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem(rl.NRName__c);
            itemsMap.put(rl.NRName__c, item);
            RemainingItems.add(item);
        }

        //request values    
        NewPlan = InventoryAMZAPI2.CreateInboundShipmentPlan(
            RemainingItems,
            'Basic'
        );

       Map<String, String> soDetailSkuMap = new Map<String, String>();  
        for(InventoryAMZAPI2.InboundShipmentPlan p : NewPlan.InboundShipmentPlans){
           soDetailSkuMap.put(p.SellerSKU, p.InStockSupplyQuantity );  
       }

         Map<String, String> soDetailSkuMap2 = new Map<String, String>();  
        for(InventoryAMZAPI2.InboundShipmentPlan p : NewPlan.InboundShipmentPlans){
            soDetailSkuMap2.put(p.SellerSKU, p.TotalSupplyQuantity  );  
        }

        //Assign values to products
        List<NRPRoducts__c> nr = [Select NRName__c FROM NRProducts__c Where NRName__c  IN: soDetailSkuMap.keySet() FOR UPDATE];
        for(NRPRoducts__c detail : nr){
            detail.AMZ_Inventory__c = Decimal.valueof(soDetailSkuMap.get(detail.NRName__c ));
            detail.AMZ_Inventory_TotalSupplyQuantity__c = Decimal.valueof(soDetailSkuMap2.get(detail.NRName__c ));
            detail.AMZ_Inventory_Last_Update__c=Datetime.now();
           detail.Inventory_Update_Cycle__c=false;


        }
         update nr;


    } else{

     numb=0;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This can happen when you have data skew issues. Do you have any child objects all related to the same parent record with more than 10K child records to the same parent?

Comment: greestork, this is the main object of the org(there are several triggers, users open these records constantly). Why  can this be an issue if I am making an update on the parent level? Is there any way to avoid or recover from this issue when it happens? thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like your org has an architecture challenge. Salesforce is not optimized to have more than 10K children associated with the same parent. Take a look at this article for how to rearchitect to avoid this issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/reducing-lock-contention-by-avoiding-account-data-skews.html

Comment: This webinar might help as well on the same topic - they talk about ways to mitigate locking e.g. sorting the values before you insert/update
https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/bulk-api

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the links. is there any way to auto-refresh the page when this happen? Thank you in advance!